# Issue retrieving generated keys with SimpleJdbcInsert and Sybase

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, sybase, jtds

I'm having an odd problem with `SimpleJdbcInsert.executeAndReturnKey` with Sybase (jTDS driver) and certain data.

Take the following example:

```
SimpleJdbcInsert insert = new SimpleJdbcInsert(jdbcTemplate)
    .withTableName("TABLE_NAME")
    .usingGeneratedKeyColumns("ID");

List<String> columns = new ArrayList<String>();
    columns.add("SOME_NUMERIC_DATA");
    columns.add("SOME_STRING_DATA");

Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
params.put("SOME_NUMERIC_DATA", 10.02);
params.put("SOME_STRING_DATA", "AAAA");

Number insertId = insert.executeAndReturnKey(params);
```

The above will fail with

```
DataIntegrityViolationException: Unable to retrieve the generated key for the insert
```

The insert itself is fine as if I do an `insert.execute(params)` the insert will work correctly (but I need the generated column value).

If I insert `null` instead of `10.02` for the `SOME_NUMERIC_DATA` column then it will work correctly and return the generated column value.  Also if all of the fields are `VARCHAR`/`String` then it will work correctly.

Can anyone see anything here that might be causing this with a combination of string and numeric fields.

*I should also add that when I use the exact same code with an H2 database it works all of the time - this seems to be related to Sybase/jTDS*

Comment: Have you verified that Sybase and/or jTDS actually support retrieval of generated keys?

Comment: It does indeed support it - and it does work if all you're persisting is strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem with SQL Server and fixed it by calling this configuration method right before the call to `executeAndReturnKey()`:

```
mySimpleJdbcInsert.setAccessTableColumnMetaData(false);
```

I suspect the error has to do with database metadata : as explained in the spring reference http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html, SimpleJdbcInsert uses database metadata to construct the actual insert statement.

One could also use the SQL OUTPUT clause such as

```
INSERT INTO myTable (Name, Age)
OUTPUT Inserted.Id
VALUES (?,?)
```

And use some more generic JdbcTemplate.execute() to handle the insert.